# How do I remove the dollar sign with str_replace in a dataframe variable in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, str-replace

I have a dataframe in R with one variable called FARE that has a dollar sign. I need to remove the dollar sign in it. How do I remove it?

```
airline.df$FARE[1] --> returns "$84.23"
```

Comment: `sub("^\\$", "", airline.df$FARE)`

Comment: I suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 for a brief regex discussion, and https://regexr.com/, https://regex101.com/ for more details and workable examples.

Comment: or if you really need to use `stringr`, then `str_replace(airline.df$FARE, "\\$", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach of replacing it with an empty char:

```
str_replace(airline.df$FARE[1], "\\$", "");
```

Or you can remove the first char ($) by creating the substring that starts with second character.

```
fare = substring(airline.df$FARE[1], 2)
```

Comment: `str_replace("$84.35", "$", "")` --> `"$84.35"`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add \\ in front, I just edited the comment.